# An approach for the analytical continuation of the Gamma Function

Tags: analysis

I found online these notes, http://math.arizona.edu/~flaschka/COURSES/527/527Notes/Gamma.pdf
On the last pages there is a line of reasoning which I am struggling to understand, I repeat herein for your convenience.
To compute the Euler Gamma function integral
$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t$$
it is suggested to split the integral obver the domains $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, the seconf integral now converging.
The first one is re-written as, having picked a natural number $n$
$$\int_0^{1}t^{z+n} \frac{e^{-t}-(1-t+t^2/2!-t^3/3!+\dots(-1)^{n}t^n/n!}{t^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}t + \sum_{k=0}^{n} \int_{0}^{1} (-1)^k\frac{t^{z-1+k}}{k!}$$
The first integral converges for $Re(z+n)>-1$ (so progress has been made towards analytically continuing the Gamma function in the real-negative half-plane), and in the notes it is stated the second integral can be integrated, which allows to get the representation therein presented.
I am struggling to see how the second integral can be integrated for $Re(z+n)>-1$, hence to follow all the approach.
Any hint on my error would be so appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> and in the notes it is stated the second integral can be integrated

Here "integrated" may just have been an unfortunate choice of words. One can easily see that for $\operatorname{Re} z \leqslant 0$, neither $\int_0^1 t^{z-1}\,dt$ nor

$$\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{t^{z-1+k}}{k!}\,dt$$

exist as a Lebesgue or improper Riemann integral.

**But**, for $\operatorname{Re} z > 0$, there is no problem, and

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \int_0^1 t^{z-1+k}\,dt = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\cdot \frac{1}{z+k}$$

is easily explicitly evaluated then, and the result is a rational function that has an obvious continuation to an entire meromorphic function.

Thus, to obtain the analytic continuation of the $\Gamma$ integral, the integral is transformed into a sum of three terms, two of which are integrals that exist for $\operatorname{Re} z > -n$, and the third is of a form whose analytic continuation is straightforward.

Comment: Daniel, many thanks for your explanation, I needed your point to be confirmed, thanks again